Visual Studio showing Merge Commit editor when going a git pull command
Recently, Visual Studio has started showing an editor for when I'm doing a git pull <remote> <branch> and there needs to be a merge.
For the last decade or so, I've been doing this command and there's never been an editor pop up. In Visual Studio, the merge was 'open', waiting for me to manually enter a commit message somewhere/somehow and the commit the merge. Or, I could abort.
I used to manually enter my own merge message into the standard Git commit window in VS:

Was there a recent setting change from MS? I know I've not:

edited my .gitconfig file
any VS settings

Lastly, this occurs for all repos, so it's not a specific setting to a specific repo.
Update 1

What is the editor?

Initially it was opening up VSCode. Now it's the VS Developer Powershell window, which I think is vi because I just do !wq<enter>

What does the command git config core.editor print?

I've not manually added any setting in to my .gitconfig but it did have a single setting for editor=vscode or something. I deleted that yesterday. Now there's no entry in it. Running the command returns nothing, at the cli.

What is the editor? What does the command git config core.editor print?

@ElpieKay answered in the O.P.
